# sbt doesn't correctly deal with resources in multi-module projects when running integration tests. Why?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have the following configuration on an sbt project:

- `moduleA` Contains a bunch of integration tests.
- `moduleB` (depends on `moduleA`). Contains a `reference.conf` file;
- `moduleC` (aggregates `moduleA` and `moduleB` -- this is the root).

When I try to run `it:test` I get errors, as the tests cannot find the values available on `reference.conf`. Manually copying the `reference.conf` to `moduleA` makes it work.

The issue seems clearly to be that by some reason when running the `it:tests` (at the root), sbt is not smart enough to add the `reference.conf` to the classpath.

Can anyone theorize why is that the case? How does sbt work with classpaths and classloaders? Will it just dump everything in a single classloader? It certainly doesn't seem to be the case.

Thanks

Comment: If `moduleB` depends on `moduleA`, and only `moduleB` contains the `reference.conf`, then why do you expect `moduleA` to be able to see the contents of `reference.conf`? Can you post a [minimal, complete & reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Aggregation is simply packaging of other modules; integration tests will be run for each module individually.

Comment: @MikeAllen: Well, it depends on how sbt runs things. I would expect both `moduleA` and `mobileB` to be shoven into the classpath, so for reference.conf to be available when you run the `it:tests` for the general project. Does sbt employ a more sophisticated loading of class files?

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, I would be grateful if you mark my answer as accepted. Otherwise, if there's anything I'm missing, let me know and I'll update the answer accordingly...

Answer (score 3):

In order to address your question and comment, let me break down what *SBT* is doing with your project.

`ModuleC` is the *root* project, and it *aggregates* `ModuleA` and `ModuleB`. In the context of *SBT*, *aggregation* means that any command that is run on the root project is also run on the aggregated sub-projects. So, for example, if you run integration tests on the root module, then you will also run the integration tests for its aggregated modules. However, it's important to understand that this is not done *all-at-once*: the command is run on each sub-project individually.

The next question that *SBT* has to address is the order in which the sub-projects should be processed. In this case, since `ModuleB` *depends on* `ModuleA`, it has to process `ModuleA` before processing `ModuleB`. Otherwise, if there was no dependency between them, then the order wouldn't matter, and *SBT* would most likely stick with the order that they were specified in `ModuleC`'s aggregation list.

But what does it mean for one sub-project to depend upon another? It's akin to the relationship between an *SBT* project and one of its `libraryDependencies`: the dependent library must be available to the sub-project, and its resources and classes are made available on the classpath during the indicated phases (compile, test, run, etc.).

So, when integration tests are run on `ModuleC`, *SBT* will first run `ModuleA`'s integration tests. Since `ModuleA` has no other dependencies within the project, it will be processed *without any of the other sub-projects available on its classpath*. (This is why it cannot access the `reference.conf` file that is part of `ModuleB`.) This makes sense, if you think about it, because otherwise—if `ModuleA` and `ModuleB` are dependent upon each other—you would have an unresolvable *chicken-and-egg* situation, in which neither project could be built.

(BTW, if `ModuleA` has sources that have not yet been compiled, then they will be compiled, on a separate compile pass, before running the integration tests.)

Next it will try to process `ModuleB`, adding `ModuleA`'s resources and classes to its classpath, since it is dependent upon them.

From your description, it seems that *at least some* of the configuration settings in `ModuleB`'s `reference.conf` file should belong to `ModuleA`, since it needs access to them during its integration tests. Whether this means that the whole of the file should belong to `ModuleA` is up to you. However, it's possible for each sub-project to have its own `reference.conf` file resource (that's a design feature of the *Typesafe Config* library that I'm assuming you're using). Any configuration settings that belong to `ModuleA`'s `reference.conf` file will also be available to `ModuleB`, since it is dependent upon `ModuleA`. (If you have multiple `reference.conf` files, the only issue you have will depend upon how you package and release `ModuleC`. If you package everything in all of your sub-projects into a single *JAR* file, then you would need to merge the various `reference.conf` files together, for example.)

Another possibility is that some or all of the integration tests should actually belong to `ModuleC` rather than either `ModuleA` or `ModuleB`. Again, making this determination will depend upon your requirements. If it makes sense for each sub-project to perform integration tests in all cases, then place them in the sub-projects. If they only make sense for the completed project as a whole, then put them in `ModuleC`.

You might want to [read the documentation for *SBT multi-project* builds](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Multi-Project.html) for further details.